# Why is node.js not finding my HTML pages

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a test directory *C:\node_samples\hello_express* set up:

[image]

I have a *package.json* file in the test directory:

```
{
  "name": "hello_express",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "A simple web site",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "Pieter Geerkens",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "4.13.4",
    "formidable":  "1.x"
  }
}
```

I have *node.js*, *express* and *formidable* properly installed in a ../node_modules subdirectory (at least, success reported from the install.) by running this command from the test directory:

```
npm install
```

I have an *app.js* file located in the test directory:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var formidable = require('formidable');

app.use('/forms', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.post('/SubmitHelloPost', function (request, response) {
   if (request.method.toLowerCase() == 'post') {
      // parse form data
      var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
      form.parse(request, function (err, fields) {
         response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
         response.write('Hello ' + fields.userName + '!<br />');
         response.end('Have a POST great day!');
         console.log('Handled POST request from ' + fields.userName);
      });
   }
});

app.get('/SubmitHello', function (request, response) {
   response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
   response.write('Hello ' + request.query.userName + '!<br />');
   response.end('Have a great day!');
   console.log('Handled GET request from ' + request.query.userName);
});

var port = 8081;
app.listen(port);
console.log('Listening on port: ' + port);
```

I open a command prompt and run *node app* as follows:

[image]

However when I attempt to run the test by navigating to either of:

```
http://localhost:8081/HelloForm.html
http://localhost:8081/HelloPost.html
```

I get an Error 404.

The html files are (*HelloForm.html*):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <form method="get" action="/SubmitHello">
      Enter Name: <input type="text" name="userName" autofocus />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and (HelloPost.html*):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
   <title></title>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
   <form method="post" action="/SubmitHelloPost">
      Enter Name: <input type="text" name="userName" autofocus />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
   </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I have no idea what is wrong. everything worked briefly after I first set it up, then stopped working.

Comment: Protip: you shouldn't include screenshots when copy-pasting from command line is enough. Use `dir` to display a content of a folder on Windows.

Comment: @Pavlo: Great point - thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your problem is caused by the following line:

```
app.use('/forms', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

This tells Express that when it receives requests starting with `/forms`, it should map those to static files in the `/public` folder. From your directory structure, I think this is what you're trying to do:

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname));
```

(It's still a good idea to move your static files to a separate directory though. Right now, navigating to `http://localhost:8081/app.js` would return the raw server-side code, which you probably don't want to be readable from your client-side code.)

Comment: Would this also expose the `app.js` script publicly? It may be safer to place the static resources into the `public` folder.

Comment: This has been painful two hours - but I will never make this particular mistake again.

Comment: @Stiliyan Yes, it would, that's what the last note is about. It's better to move the `.html` files to a `/public` folder and change the route to `app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));` I first explain how to solve the initial problem, then how to improve upon it. :-)

Comment: Got it, I see you amended your answer.

Answer (score 3):

You should make a directory for those files (I'll use 'public' for this example). Then move the files you want to serve to it, and then change

```
app.use('/forms', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

to

```
app.use('/', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

The first argument is the server directory where clients access the files, which you want to be the root directory (i.e. '/'), and the second argument is where the files are stored. Usually you don't want to mix your public content (like html), with private content, like server logic, so you put it in a separate folder and only serve that content.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there are at least 2 problems.

#### Problem #1

You've mounted your static asset directory at the `/forms` path, meaning any static assets you want to retrieve will be found at `http://localhost:8081/forms/SomeFileName`. You are trying to locate them directly at `http://localhost:8081/HelloForm.html`, which won't work. If you want to get rid of the `/forms` part of the path entirely, then you can remove the path argument entirely from your static asset declaration:

`app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

#### Problem #2

You don't have these files inside the public directory anyway. They're just sitting out in your root directory. Instead you want them to be inside a folder called `public`, so that your static asset declaration can find them. That's why it has the word `public` in it, like so:

`app.use('/forms', express.static(__dirname + '/public'));`

So instead, create a folder in the root directory called `public` and move both those files (HelloForm.html and HelloPost.html) into there.

Here are the [Express docs on static file serving](http://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html), which show you how it works in more detail.

However, I'm guessing that even though this will work to display those 2 files, this is probably not what you ultimately want to do. My guess is that you want to use the 2 routes you've defined to show these 2 pages. My recommendation would be to read up on [using a View Engine like EJS](https://scotch.io/tutorials/use-ejs-to-template-your-node-application) to render dynamic views, and also read up on [RESTful routing](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-beginners-guide-to-http-and-rest--net-16340) to determine how to name your routes.